# Company completion backend company-capf error error

Tags: lsp-mode, company

I am using `lsp-mode` and `company` on top of Pyhton files. When I complete a function I am getting follwing error:

`Company: backend company-capf error "[yas] ‘yas-expand-snippet’ needs properly setup ‘yas-minor-mode’" with args (post-completion get_job_block_number(requester_address, key, index))`

---

Completed function example:

`self.mongo_broker.get_job_block_number(${1:requester_address}, ${2:key}, ${3:index})$0`

which should be just: `self.mongo_broker.get_job_block_number()`

my setup:

```
(diminish 'yas-minor-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)

(setq company-auto-complete t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-k") 'company-complete)
```

What may be the reason of this error and how can I resolve it?

---

// Could be related with following question: [Company: backend company-capf error](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62183/company-backend-company-capf-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I was missing (`yas-global-mode`) call. When I added to my `.emacs` file problem is resolved.

Comment: show exactly what you inserted.  Because I have this exact problem.